# boot optimisation, takes too long

Tags: unity, boot

I can't seem to get my system (asrock ion 330, ocz agility 4 120GB, 4GB, 11.10) to boot in under 30ish seconds.

I would expect having an SSD, things could boot a bit faster... main challenge seems to be compiz/unity but there is also a 4-5 initial sec boot delay between starting the keyboard driver and mounting the disk:

```
[    **2.825511**] generic-usb 0003:046D:C318.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech Logitech Illuminated Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:04.1-5.4/input1
[    **7.037201**] EXT4-fs (sda2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    7.037278] EXT4-fs (sda2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    7.241351] EXT4-fs (sda2): recovery complete
[    7.241720] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

[image: bootchart]

Greatly appreciate your thoughts/advice.

Comment: Full dmesg output could be useful, there's not much to go on there. 30s is pretty respectable to be honest. The weak CPU accounts for most of it after the initial burst of disk. The 5 second delay to mount root seems excessive, but I note it needs recovery, are you shutting down cleanly every time?

Comment: It looks like it is CPU bound, not I/O bound, so the SSD is doing its work. Looks like disabling Plymouth (splash in boot line) can help a bit, but I agree that the main save could be reduce that 5 seconds waiting for root.

Comment: below my dmesg. no log entries between keyboard and drive. I always do a clean shutdown but I also always see the recovery (both with my previous HDD and now with my SSD).  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23858059/dmesg

Answer (score 4):

The five second delay at the beginning is caused by a mismatch between the UUIDs from the swap partition and what the initrd is expecting.

1. From a terminal, run:

   ```
   sudo blkid | grep swap
   ```

   If you see something like:

   ```
   /dev/sdb3: UUID="4b5fc336-fc27-48cc-9475-04ba2d01cf3c" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   copy the UUID.
2. Now fix the UUID that initrd is expecting:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
   ```

   and replace the old UUID with the one from above (without the quotes).
3. Finally, recreate the initrd:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
   ```

   Next boot should be five seconds faster.

If you don't have a swap partition, it should be sufficient to just remove the `resume` file:

```
sudo rm /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

and then follow step 3.

Comment: I was so excited seeing this answer, until I discovered that there were no differences between my UUIDs for swap. However, my `fstab` lists an older OS that also has a swap partition, could this be causing a slower boot?